# Finding minimum and maximum from array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm working on a project that involves importing data from a CSV file into a C# program using an array and returning values such as the minimum and maximum. I've been having a bit of trouble implementing a way to return the max and min values.

Samples class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
namespace Thomas_Nicholas_E2
{
    class Samples
    {
        public double Fenner { get; set; }
        public double Abom { get; set; }

        public Samples()
        {

        }

        public void ReadCsv(StreamReader reader)
        {
            string buffer;
            string[] parts;

            // Get record from file
            buffer = reader.ReadLine();

            // Break record into components
            parts = buffer.Split(',');

           /* Array.Sort<string>(parts);
            foreach (var x in parts)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(x);
            }
            */
            // Convert field values to variable
            Fenner = Convert.ToDouble(parts[0]);
            Abom = Convert.ToDouble(parts[1]);


            // Finding the range of the datasets 
            //var sortedFenner = parts[0].OrderBy(i => i);
            //var sortedAbom = parts[1].OrderBy(i => i);
            //var sortedTotal = parts.OrderBy(i => i);
            //Console.WriteLine(sortedAbom);
            //Console.WriteLine(parts.Max());
            //double minimum1 = Math.Min(parts, parts);
            //Console.WriteLine(parts[1].Min());

            //string min = parts[0].Min();
            // Console.WriteLine(min);
            //double min = parts[1].Min();
            //Console.WriteLine(min);
        }

    }
}
```

You can see what I've tried so far in the commented out section at the bottom of the Samples class.

Programs class just in case:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Thomas_Nicholas_E2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("examdata.csv");

            string buffer;

            double totalFenner = 0.0;
            double totalAbom = 0.0;
            double total = 0.0;
            double minumum = 0.0;
            double maximum = 0.0;
            double range = 0.0;
            double meanFenner = 0.0;
            double meanAbom = 0.0;
            double meanTotal = 0.0;

            // Read header to get it out of the way
            buffer = reader.ReadLine();

            while(!reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                Samples MySamples = new Samples();
                MySamples.ReadCsv(reader);

                // Processing
                //Calculating totals
                totalFenner += MySamples.Fenner;
                totalAbom += MySamples.Abom;
                total = (totalFenner + totalAbom);

                //Calculating means
                meanFenner = (totalFenner / 20);
                meanAbom = (totalAbom / 20);
                meanTotal = (total / 40);


                // += MySamples;

                //Console.WriteLine("TransId: {0}  DeptNo: {1}  Amt: {2}", transId, deptNo, amt);
                //MyTransaction.Print();
            }
            Console.WriteLine(meanFenner);
            Console.WriteLine(meanAbom);
            Console.WriteLine(meanTotal);
            //Console.WriteLine(Samples.sortedAbom)




            reader.Close();

            Pause();
        }
        private static void Pause()
        {
            Console.Write("Press any key to continue...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

I appreciate any advice or guidance, thank you.

Comment: Read all items to a collection and use System.Linq namespace and Min() Max() methods.

Comment: It seems you are only reading one line from the csv file. you need to read all lines.

Comment: string.Split() is an awful way to handle csv values.

Comment: You have an array of two values part[0] is the first value of an array, not an array, this is why you cannot call part[0].Min()

Comment: It really would help if you posted a few lines from examdata.csv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build the `ReadCsv()` method in the `Samples` class with overloaded [Factory pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) methods, like this:

```
public static Samples ReadCsv(StreamReader reader)
{
    return ReadCSv(reader.ReadLine());
}

public static Samples ReadCsv(string line)
{
    parts = line.Split(',');
    return new Samples() {
        Fenner = Convert.ToDouble(parts[0]),
        Abom = Convert.ToDouble(parts[1])
    };
}
```

And then you can use it from your `Main()` method like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var samples = File.ReadLines("examdata.csv")
                 .Select(l => Samples.ReadCsv(l))
                 .ToList();

    double totalFenner = samples.Select(s => s.Fenner).Sum();
    double totalAbom = samples.Select(s => s.Abom).Sum();
    double total = totalFenner + totalAbom;

    double meanFenner = sampes.Select(s => s.Fenner).Avg();
    double meanAbom = samples.Select(s => s.Abom).Avg();
    double meanTotal = samples.Select(s => s.Fenner + s.Abom).Avg();

    Console.WriteLine(meanFenner);
    Console.WriteLine(meanAbom);
    Console.WriteLine(meanTotal);

     Pause();
}
```

or like this (more code, but runs faster and easier for some to understand):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    double totalFenner = 0.0;
    double totalAbom = 0.0;
    double total = 0.0;

    double meanFenner = 0.0;
    double meanAbom = 0.0;
    double meanTotal = 0.0;

    var samples = File.ReadLines("examdata.csv")
                 .Select(l => Samples.ReadCsv(l));

    int count = 0;
    foreach (var sample in samples)
    {
        totalFenner += sample.Fenner;
        totalAbom += sample.Abom;
        count++;
    }
    total = totalFenner + totalAbom;
    meanTotal = total / count;
    meanFenner = totalFenner / count;
    meanAbom = totalAbom / count;

    Console.WriteLine(meanFenner);
    Console.WriteLine(meanAbom);
    Console.WriteLine(meanTotal);

     Pause();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this really helped me out.

Answer (score 0):

Finding the min/max is trivially easy. Assuming an array or list you can simply call `.Min()` or `.Max()` on it. For example:

```
var foo = new List<int> {4,3,5,9,1};
var min = foo.Min();
var max = foo.Max();
```

Answer (score 0):

I thought it might be useful to provide some code for some of the answers that I've seen in the comments.

To read all the lines you could do something like:

```
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("examdata.csv")) {

      while ((buffer = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
      {
         // Something
      }

    }
```

And then if you're using an array, you can do something like what @gilliduck said and find the min/max values with `.Min()` or `.Max()`.